# Linux shows several folders with the exact same name

Tags: linux, macos, ls, ext4

I recently used a mac to copy several files and folders to a USB drive (ext4 through ExtFS), and now in Linux (Xbian) two folders in the root of the drive are shown four times. The output of "ls -lQai" is:

```
total 2176
   2 drwxr-xr-x  9 root root      73728 Jun  3 01:32 "."
6533 drwxr-xr-x 10 root root       4096 Jun  2 01:41 ".."
  16 -rw-r--r--  1  501 dialout   21508 Jun  3 01:30 ".DS_Store"
  12 d-wx-wx-wt  2 root      99    4096 Jun  3 01:32 ".Trashes"
  17 -rw-r--r--  1   99      99    4096 Jun  2 02:17 "._.DS_Store"
  13 --w-------  1   99      99    4096 Jun  2 02:16 "._.Trashes"
2186 -rwxrwxrwx  1   99      99    4096 Jun  2 06:03 "._Videos"
  26 -rw-r--r--  1  501 dialout     308 Jun  2 02:43 ".apdisk"
 524 drwxr-xr-x  5  501 dialout    4096 Jun  3 01:22 "Photos"
 524 drwxr-xr-x  5  501 dialout    4096 Jun  3 01:22 "Photos"
 524 drwxr-xr-x  5  501 dialout    4096 Jun  3 01:22 "Photos"
 524 drwxr-xr-x  5  501 dialout    4096 Jun  3 01:22 "Photos"
  18 drwxrwxrwx  4  501 dialout    4096 Jun  3 01:27 "Videos"
 533 drwxr-xr-x  2  501 dialout    4096 Jun  3 01:30 "_meta"
 533 drwxr-xr-x  2  501 dialout    4096 Jun  3 01:30 "_meta"
 533 drwxr-xr-x  2  501 dialout    4096 Jun  3 01:30 "_meta"
 533 drwxr-xr-x  2  501 dialout    4096 Jun  3 01:30 "_meta"
 516 drwxr-xr-x  2  501 dialout 2043904 Jun  3 01:13 "_thumbs"
  11 drwx------  2 root root      16384 Jun  2 01:47 "lost+found"
2560 drwxr-xr-x  6  501 dialout    4096 Jun  3 01:31 "backup_2013-05-31"
```

The drive is working fine and the contents are ok, but it's really bugging me.

Comment: I guess the directories lead all into the same directory? Did you try to run fsck on it?

Comment: @Bobby: +1 for `fsck`. All "same-named" dirs have the same `inode` number, so they should point to the very same directory.

Comment: BACKUP FIRST before any fsck!

Comment: "fsck /dev/sda1" outputs this: "/dev/sda1: clean, 7464/91578368 files, 272464388/366284390 blocks". I'm very new to linux, should I try with some options?

Comment: Ok, fsck -f did the trick, thanks all. Bobby, if you set your comment as answer I'll accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run fsck on this partition:
[examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/fsck-command-examples/)

Do not forget unmount partition before and mount it back after fsck process.

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really good answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: are comments that are just a link, and are not even really pertinent in this case really good comments? Am I passive-aggressively indicating that the comment I'm refering to is not actually a good comment IMO?